# Get current metadatasize for an physical volume

Tags: linux, lvm, lvm2

Is there a way to get the current metadatasize for a phyisical volume. I used

```
[root@i-6b4fb096 ~]# pvcreate --metadatasize 10000 /dev/sda4
  Physical volume "/dev/sda4" successfully created
[root@i-6b4fb096 ~]# pvdisplay /dev/sda4
  "/dev/sda4" is a new physical volume of "39.99 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda4
  VG Name               
  PV Size               39.99 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               ZcTGAv-L4D9-Gxvw-p9BE-Ay19-Ccql-bSIJN8
```

But, I've checked in man pages of this command -also using pvdisplay - and I can't find any information that let me know that parameter was setup with properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
$ pvs --units k -o pv_mda_count,pv_mda_free,pv_mda_size /dev/sda4
#PMda PMdaFree  PMdaSize
    1   507.50k  1020.00k
```

Comment: I had to change the script, but it worked :) Thank you.